# PictureBox Is Nowhere To Be Seen

Tags: c#, winforms, image, visual-studio-2013, picturebox

I've been experimenting with adding elements to Windows Forms dynamically via code.
I need to create a PictureBox element. So, far, I have the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //stylise form
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

        PictureBox bgui = new PictureBox();
        bgui.Image = Properties.Resources.attack_box;
        bgui.Name = "bgui";
        bgui.Location = new Point(0, 600);
        this.Controls.Add(bgui);
        bgui.Visible = true;

    }
```

However, when this code is run, I get nothing but the black background which I set earlier. I've looked at many questions similar to mine; and they all say I need to add it to the control, which I have done, yet it still abstains from showing.

I would really appreciate it if you could give me an insight into my wrong-doing.

Thanks, Computo.

Comment: maybe your image is whats is not loading. what I do in this case bgui.borderstyle=BorderStyle.Fixed3D so you can see where it is.

Comment: 600 is a bit high.  Make it smaller or set it to this.ClientSize.Height - bgui.Height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Width` and `Height` Properties of the `PictureBox`.

Try This:

```
    bgui.Width = 500;
    bgui.Height = 500;
```

**Complete Code:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //stylise form
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

    PictureBox bgui = new PictureBox();
    bgui.Image = Properties.Resources.attack_box;
    bgui.Name = "bgui";
    bgui.Width = 500;
    bgui.Height = 500;
    bgui.Location = new Point(0, 600);
    this.Controls.Add(bgui);
    bgui.Visible = true;

}
```

Comment: I've set it to the dimensions of the image of w:800, h:200. Still a black screen. :/

Comment: @Computoguy: you can try what bto.rdx told and also please make sure that you set your Picturebox Y axis 600 so it is far down, you can set it to 300 or some top level to identify your picture.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `System.Drawing.Point` does not translate to the actual pixels on the screen. I will have to investigate how `Point` translates into pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Here its works perfect. Specify the SizeMode and change the location.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //stylise form
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

        PictureBox bgui = new PictureBox();
        bgui.Image = Properties.Resources.attack_box;
        bgui.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 0);
        bgui.Name = "pictureBox1";
        bgui.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.Controls.Add(bgui);
    }
```